# VB.NET datagrid - detect combo box selection and select same value in different column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrid with combo boxes. Now I want to achieve that if on selects value x in column 0 row 0 then then combo box value y in colum 1 row 0 is set to the same value like x automatically.

I tried

```
 Private Sub dataGridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles Sched_Grid.CellValidating
    If Sched_Grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Sched_Grid(1, Sched_Grid.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value = Sched_Grid(0, Sched_Grid.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

However, it doesnt work immediately. I have to first selected a value x(0,0), then click a different cell(5,5 or something else) and then click back into x(0,0) cell so that y(1,0) gets set to x(0,0).

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `EditingControlShowing` event to get to the underlying control and then add another handler.  It gets a little messy though.

```
Private Sub Sched_Grid_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender as Object, Byval e as DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles Sched_Grid.EditingControlShowing
  If Sched_Grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    Dim selectedComboBox As Combobox = DirectCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
    RemoveHandler selectedCombobox.SelectionChangeCommitted, AddressOf selectedComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted
    AddHandler selectedCombobox.SelectionChangeCommitted, AddressOf selectedComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub selectedComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  Dim selectedCombobox As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
  If selectedCombobox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    Sched_Grid(1, Sched_Grid.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value = selectedCombobox.SelectedItem
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code! the event fires properly, however the selectedCombobox Value is still empty. I am not expert enough to find the error in your code. Maybe someone else sees the bug....

Comment: @user670186, Is the selectedCombobox have a datasource?  If so, have you specified that `ValueMember`?  If not, use `selectedCombobox.SelectedItem` to get your value.  (You might need to cast it to the correct data type.)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to the [CurrencyManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.aspx) class to bind both controls to the same collection. On the `ComboBox` you can use the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) property to display only the column you want.

Simple example: http://www.vb-tips.com/CurrencyManager.aspx